# Need to get descendent items list in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, hierarchy

***Description:***

There is table wich consist of two columns (ParentId and ChildId) that displays hierarchy of some entities. Each Id could be presented in ParentId column only one time. That means that each entity have only one child entity.

***Problem:*** I need to check whether entity(its Id) is in descendants list of parent entity.

Comment: Are you trying to do cycle detection?

Comment: Is there a unique constraint on ParentID?

Comment: The pair of ParentId and ChildId is unique constraint. But no other constraints in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityHierarchy]
(
    [EntityId] INT,
    [ChildEntityId] INT
)

INSERT  [dbo].[EntityHierarchy]
VALUES  (1, 2),
        (2, 3),
        (3, 4),
        (4, 1) -- Cycle
```

Find circular relationships:

```
DECLARE @SearchEntityId INT = 1

;WITH [cteRursive] AS
(
    SELECT  1 AS [ROW_NUMBER],
            [ChildEntityId] AS [EntityId]
    FROM [dbo].[EntityHierarchy]
    WHERE [EntityId] = @SearchEntityId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  r.[ROW_NUMBER] + 1,
            h.[ChildEntityId]
    FROM [cteRursive] r
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[EntityHierarchy] h 
        ON r.[EntityId] = h.[EntityId]
    WHERE h.[ChildEntityId] <> @SearchEntityId
)
SELECT h.*
FROM [cteRursive] r
INNER JOIN [dbo].[EntityHierarchy] h 
    ON r.[EntityId] = h.[EntityId]
WHERE r.[ROW_NUMBER] = (SELECT MAX([ROW_NUMBER]) FROM [cteRursive])
```

I'm using a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) to list the descendants.  The *child* of the last descendant either creates a cycle or not.

Comment: Nice pointing, but I just need to check whether or not ChildId is in descendants list of ParentId. Wihout any cycle.

Comment: I updated a little this CTE and it works fine. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @parentId INT
DECLARE @childId INT
DECLARE @targetChildId INT
SET @targetChildId=<put id of a child you want to find>
SET @parentId=<put id of a parent you are looking child for>
SET @childId=0

WHILE (@childId<>@targetChildId)
    BEGIN
        IF(EXISTS(SELECT ChildId FROM Hierarchies WHERE ParentId=@parentId))
        BEGIN
            SET @childId=(SELECT ChildId FROM Hierarchies WHERE ParentId=@parentId)
            SET @parentId=@childId
        END 
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @childId=0
            BREAK
        END
    END
PRINT @childId
```

It returns 0 if target child not found in target parent.